# sending new messages to this bot has been disabled by your administrator in teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am unable to chat with teams bot i am getting  message like "sending new messages to this bot has been disabled by your administrator in teams" instead of showing text box

Comment: How did you add your Bot to Teams? Remember you need to have Apps sideloading enabled in your teams settings to properly deploy your bot.

Comment: As the message says, you should contact your administrator(s). They disabled one or more applications in your tenant.

Answer (score 2):

I've also encountered my custom bot having the disabled presence, whilst the same bot on a different tenant had the available presence.

As suggested in the comments, you or your Teams admin need to check the box 'Allow interaction with custom apps':

1. Teams admin center
2. Team apps
3. Manage apps
4. Org-wide app settings
   [image: Teams admin center - Manage apps]
5. Check 'Allow interaction with custom apps'
   [image: Allow interation with custom apps]